# Error using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

I'm trying to use the SimpleDateFormat class to parse a DateTime out of this string:

05-Jul-2012 11:38:02,442 UTC AM

I tried the following format string:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformatYYYYMMDD = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS z a");

Date temp = dateformatYYYYMMDD.parse(time);
```

But it generates the error:

Error: Unparseable date: ""

If I use zZ I get : Error: Unparseable date: "05-Jul-2012 11:38:02,442 UTC AM"

Any hints on how to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works fine for me when I try to run:

```
String time = "05-Jul-2012 11:38:02,442 UTC AM";
SimpleDateFormat dateformatYYYYMMDD = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS z a");
Date temp = dateformatYYYYMMDD.parse(time);
```

Are you sure `time` is set to something?

Comment: I think you're right! I don't get the error when I do it like this... the time I get it reading a line of a log file...

Comment: @deb add some code to check that `time` is actually a date string, because the exception you get `Error: Unparseable date: ""` seems to indicate that `time` is a blank string.

Answer (score 6):

The code you've given works fine for me. Perhaps the problem is your locale? Try specifying it when you create the `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat format =new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS z a",
                                              Locale.US);
```

That way it will try to find US month and am/pm designator names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS z a",
                                              Locale.US).format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your error. Are you sure you are using:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```