# SimpleDateFormat parse function changing the format

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

I have a String with several dates:

[20-Jul-2012 5:11:36,670 UTC PM, 20-Jul-2012 5:11:36,683 UTC PM]

```
ParsePosition parsePos = new ParsePosition(1);
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS z a");
System.out.println(format2.parse(entry.getValue().toString(), parsePos)) ;
```

Output : `Fri Jul 20 06:11:36 BST 2012`

I need the output to be `20-Jul-2012 5:11:36,670 UTC PM`.

Do I need to set a LOCALE in the `SimpleDateFormat` to not have a different output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract date from String java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599591/extract-date-from-string-java)

Comment: Is this the same question? If not, please edit this one here to be clearly distinct from your other question... or the one you've asked a couple of days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507845/error-using-simpledateformat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the time zone, but more importantly, you simply need to actually use the format to format the date:

```
Date date = format2.parse(...);
String formattedDate = format2.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

What your code does is:

```
Date date = format2.parse(...);
System.out.println(date.toString());
```

I don't really understand the point in parsing a string to a date, and then displaying the date using the exact same format, though (except to validate that the String is indeed a valid date, but then you could simply reuse the original string).

Answer (score 1):

You've got two small problems:

1. Use `hh` for the hour, not `HH`. `H` is "Hour in day (0-23), and so will not work correctly with `a`, the AM/PM marker. Your two example date strings will parse to AM, not PM.
2. You're using SimpleDateFormat to parse the string, but not format it. Use `format2.format(format2.parse(entry.getValue().toString())`.

Here's a complete example:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss,SSS z a");
String input = "20-Jul-2012 5:11:36,670 UTC PM";
Date date = format.parse(input);
String output = format.format(date);
System.out.println(output);
```

Result:

```
20-Jul-2012 05:11:36,670 UTC PM
```